# Windows 10 KMCS Development Testing

Tags: windows, testing, kernel, driver, windows-10

So I've spent a good day or two frustratedly googling for how you can develop 64 bit Kernel-Mode drivers in **Windows 10** (does not apply to Win8 or earlier), and specifically **test** in the development environment.

Basically I have a physical harddrive kernel-mode driver that "mounts" a virtual drive like a physical drive and maps the Win32 CreateFile API's to a user mode application that then routes the commands to a remote network on another server (similar to VPN but custom, flexible).

I use this to install **and run** programs and store files on a remote system so it needs to be an emulated physical drive (Network Attached has too much limitations, and instabilities). - This is similar to SAN, except in a non-corporate network.

So my question(s) are, does anyone else frustrate about Microsoft completely blocking out us developers from kernel mode developing **for personal use**, when you do not have the economy to buy a certificate?

And what options do I have for running my driver on **my** Windows 10 computer, without purchased certificates?

There doesn't seem to be any ways to circumvent the new EV certificate system which completely forces you to buy certificate, even if you know what you're doing and you accept the risk of making your system vulnerable.

If you have no knowledge of Windows 10 KMCS driver development, please leave the questions to the experienced, as Windows 8 doesn't require the new EV system.

Microsoft's path is also forcing free-software organizations to be unable to invent any hardware interop systems, VPN, file systems and more with these certificate enforcements since economically only the bigger companies will afford the certificates.

Reference articles:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_hardware_certification/archive/2015/04/01/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10.aspx
- https://www.osr.com/blog/2015/03/18/microsoft-signatures-required-km-drivers-windows-10/

Also here is an article about what's now impossible to do without legitimate certificates in Windows 10
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58950/How-to-develop-a-virtual-disk-for-Windows

Comment: Your options are: (1) buy an EV cert, or (2) boot to test-signing mode on every boot. If you don't like Microsoft's choices about how to run their platform, feel free to switch to a different OS.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552275(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You should also investigate whether you can use a user-mode driver instead.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That link doesnt contain much (or any) information regarding Windows 10 procedure. Also, file system drivers (and more) cannot be done in User-Mode (UMDF)

Comment: @Nicco: according to your first link, the procedure for testing has not been changed in Windows 10.  So just follow the Windows 8 instructions.  If you've tried that and failed, then you should post the details.  As for UMDF, your question is vague as to what kind of driver you're dealing with, but you linked to an article about a storage driver, not a file system driver.  So far as I can see storage drivers *can* be UMDF.  At least it would be worth *trying*.

Comment: I'm working with this https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany but it's not fully completed for use in "release" environment, so I need to be able to change the kernel-code. But there is no information regarding Windows 10, while I already know it works fine on Windows 8. Remember that I'm trying to install the kernel driver as a functional driver that starts upon bootup every time because I will depend on it, while having the ability to update its code when needed - as I did in Windows 8.

Comment: I'm still not sure what your problem is.  What did you do to make it work on Windows 8 - had you purchased a certificate?  Why can't you use test-signing mode?